# Unity - Snap to grid while following mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Trying to create a Connect 4-like game. I made the board model have it's holes aligned with the grid so I can easily drop the circles into them.

Problem is I don't know how to, in unity, make the object follow the mouse while also snapping to a grid.

Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LockToGrid : MonoBehaviour {
    public float gridSize;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        SnapToGrid(gameObject);
    }

    void SnapToGrid(GameObject Object) {
        var currentPos = Object.transform.position;
        Object.transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Round(currentPos.x / gridSize) * gridSize,
                                     currentPos.y,
                                     currentPos.z);

    }
}
```

Comment: Add an invisible target above the rows, if this is unity 5 you can just use in invisible image  check to see if your mouse is over the target, place the check piece in the target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I've done this](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/util/MathHelper.cs#L69-L87) before.  I have these in my own math class (MathHelper). It snaps the values to multiples of another value (how far away each slot in your game is).

```
    public static Vector3 snap(Vector3 pos, int v) {
        float x = pos.x;
        float y = pos.y;
        float z = pos.z;
        x = Mathf.FloorToInt(x / v) * v;
        y = Mathf.FloorToInt(y / v) * v;
        z = Mathf.FloorToInt(z / v) * v;
        return new Vector3(x, y, z);
    }

    public static int snap(int pos, int v) {
        float x = pos;
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(x / v) * v;
    }

    public static float snap(float pos, float v) {
        float x = pos;
        return Mathf.FloorToInt(x / v) * v;
    }
```

So after getting the value based on the mouse position, run it through snap, then apply the result to your GameObject's transform position. Like so:

`transform.position = MathHelper.snap(Input.MousePosition, 24);`

You might have to fiddle with it, if the `Input.MousePosition` isn't directly convertable to your coordinate space, as well as the snap distance (24 is from my own usage, yours might be 1, 5, 10, 50, or 100).

Comment: How do you get around the issue of when imprecision occurs and you get 1.99999 instead of 2 and it ends up flooring by 1 tile when it shouldn't?

Comment: @WDUK You'd have to supply an example set of inputs that results in floating point division that's off by an amount less than epsilon in that manner. I'd wager that either (a) no examples exist for small values that could be reasonably assumed to be in use or (b) that the error amount is less than the user would notice.

Comment: Well say for just x axis for now i had an origin point of 1.2345 and world point of 2.2345. Subtracting the difference then flooring to get the tile position you should get 1 but some times the difference is calculated as 0.9999 instead of 1 or 1.0001 and thus if you have 0.9999 and floor it, it goes to tile number 0 instead of 1. Since in my case my grid tile (0,0) doesn't necessary go to world (0,0) position.

Comment: *`Since in my case my grid tile (0,0) doesn't necessary go to world (0,0) position`* Ok, you're right, I didn't account for that. I'm also not going to fix it to handle it, use local positions and `Transform.TransformPoint()` and work in local coordinates where grid-(0,0) is local-(0,0).

Comment: I do already, the issue is world point from mouse converted to local point is where the imprecision starts to creep in. I don't know how people usually solve for it.

Comment: Try adding `float.epsilon` before flooring.