# I want to generate obj at random places which can move in random speed in X axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-physics

I am working on something. In this project I want to generate a object at random position which can go left to right continuously. So far I have got this.

This is inside start of a class that generate 50 object on which player can jump on when game loads.

```
void Start () {

Vector2 pos = transform.position;

for(int i = 0; i < noOfHolder; i++)

{ pos.x = Random.Range(-3, 3);

pos.y += Random.Range(1, 5);

Instantiate(holder, pos, Quaternion.identity);

}
```

and

the holder object which is attached to it have a method.

```
updatePosition(){
//moveSpeed = Random.Range(1,3);tried this
startingPos.x = moveSpeed * Mathf.Sin(Time.time);//*moveSpeed

transform.position = startingPos;}

​
```

This code can generate multiple objects. but with the same sin speed from left to right.

I change the move speed. Some obj move to the half of the screen some full. I want all the object move to full screen with vary speed.

Thank you for answering.

​

Comment: In the Start method of the holder object define the moveSpeed = Random.Range(1,3) not in update.
also if u want the objects to move from left to right you will need a flag to define at which offset the object will start to move backwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
void Start()
{
    Vector2 pos = transform.position;
    for(int i = 0; i < noOfHolder; i++)
    {
        pos.x = Random.Range(-3, 3);
        pos.y += Random.Range(1, 5);
        Instantiate(holder, pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }
    moveSpeed = Random.Range(1,3);
    moveDistance = 1.0f;
}

void Update()
{
    startingPos.x = moveDistance * Mathf.Sin(Time.time * moveSpeed);
    transform.position = startingPos;
}
```

if this is not what you want, please describe your situation in more detail and i will edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @user5234003 if it works, please upvote and accept the answer. thank you!

Comment: ryte now i am not eligible for this..:)

Comment: you need 15 reputation to upvote (the orange triangle), but i think that you can still accept the answer (the green check mark) :)

Comment: hank you so much for this. With your help I am able to Complete my first game. I don't have any other way to contact you so . Thank you . I am attaching the link where i have mention you name hope you don't mind. https://gamejolt.com/games/myWorld/366507

Comment: @user5234003 no problem, glad i could help! thank you for the mention, i don't mind at all :) i played your game - quite good for your first game. it is good to see someone actually complete a project :) (i abandoned my first 3 games because they were too complicated)

Comment: Thank you. I have heard start with simple and complete those first. Because it is quite hard to develop complicated project in starting.:)

Comment: @jini Hey thank you  for helping. With your help I am able to make my 3rd game. Please check once if you have little time.
https://lifeisjourney.itch.io/snowman

Comment: @user5234003 i see you are making progress :) perhaps see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44707183/4675770 for weapon placement ;)

Comment: @jini , Hey jini, How are you.. I want to ask you something. Can you share your Insta link? Thanks

Comment: i don't have instagram... you can ask me here or ask a new question and paste the link here or use chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: sir, I tried asking question but it was art related question  and because of that it was deleted by moderator..:) and how I chat with with you... Sorry for troubling you.. But I can trust you thats why I want to chat with you... thank you.

Comment: art related? if you mean game graphics, you can ask your question on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ and send me the link. if you mean graphic design, you can ask your question on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ and send me the link :)

Comment: Thanks Jini, earlier I posted on this site thats why they deleted that . Now I get it .:). I have Posted the question again. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/167042/want-to-ask-art-creation-for-indie-game-developer   Thanks you again.